# "The style 'dropShadowVisible' is only supported by type 'mx.controls.List' with the theme(s) 'spark'" Flex theme warning

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark, halo

What can I do to remove this warning in Flex? I'm using the Halo theme and do not want to use the Spark theme.

> The style 'dropShadowVisible' is only supported by type 'mx.controls.List' with the theme(s) 'spark'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1) Set the compiler argument 'warnings' to false.  [More info about compiler arguments are in the docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html).  Other compiler arguments that related to this are show-actionscript-warnings and warn-warning_type.

2) Make sure all the classes you're using do not reference the dropShadowVisible style.  Most likely it is used internally be Flex Framework classes that you are using in your app; so that may require some extending.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://jacksenechal.com/blog/2010/12/using-flex-4-with-the-flex-3-halo-theme/) might give you some insight.(I have not verified the solution posted there).I advise you to take a backup copy of the framework.swc mentioned before you make changes.[This bug](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-25720) filed in the adobe bug repository also has some information

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises whenever you use an mx|List, in an app with the Spark theme, and with SDK 4.0 or 4.1. The Adobe bug mentioned earlier has been fixed, and the fix is in SDK 4.5.